# How can I go to the implementation of angular source code?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

How can we jump to the implementation of angular source code in IntelliJ Idea (Ultimate)?

e.g. when I CTRL-click on `Validators.max` the IDE will take me to the declaration in `validators.d.ts` - but I want to see the actual source code in the [validators.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bba5e2632e6f940d828023a4bebccfd0f9c4893b/packages/forms/src/validators.ts#L125) file.

In Java applications we can [attach sources](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206191239-Attach-sources-to-jars-the-easy-way) of jar files, to make this feature work.

Comment: have  you check `validators.ts` present in your node module or not?

Comment: @Abhishek Not, it is not there (only `.d.ts` and `.js`). Can I add some configuration to download the ts-sources?

Comment: @angular package distribution doesn't include source `.ts` files - only compiled bundles and declaration files, so there is no way for IDEA to navigate to them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These instructions are for WebStorm, but I assume the steps are similar to IntelliJ.

You need to checkout the Angular source code to a directory, and you have to match the version of the source code to the installed version for your project.

So look in your `package.json` file for the version

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.3",
    ...
}
```

Now checkout that version to a local directory (minor versions are X).

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/angular
cd angular
git checkout 7.1.x
```

In your editor go to `File / Settings / Languages & Frameworks` and select `JavaScript`.

The dialog looks like this:

[image]

Click the "Add..." button and open the "New Library" dialog. Type in the "name" as "Angular", and then click the "+" button to add files. Select the "Add directories..." button and pick the directory where you cloned the Angular project.

You will now have an Angular library installed into the IDE, but keep in mind this will have no impact on compiling your projects. It will just include the source code with intellisense features, and when you CTRL+CLICK an Angular definition it will take you directly to the source code.